# How to split string before Binding in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a Linq query like this:

```
var result = from c in db.Class
                 join s in db.Students on c.Cls_Id equals s.Cls_Id
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Stud_Id,
                     s.FirstName,
                     c.Cls_Id,
                     c.Room,
                     c.Notification
                 };
repeater.DataSource = result.ToList();
repeater.DataBind();
```

But in Notification field has content like this: This Room of C Programming Class/NTFF. If binding in Lable `Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Notification")%>'` it will display: **This Room of C Programming Class/NTFF**.

I want to split this string into 2 string like this:

> str1 = This Room of C Programming Class;
>
> str2 = NTFF;

before binding and binding str1 into Lable1 and str2 into Lable2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to get `str1` like this:-

```
 var result = from c in db.Class
                 join s in db.Students on c.Cls_Id equals s.Cls_Id
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Stud_Id,
                     s.FirstName,
                     c.Cls_Id,
                     c.Room,
                     str1 = c.Notification.Split('/').FirstOrDefault()
                 };
```

Then, you can bind it to your Label like this:-

```
<asp:Lable Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "str1")%>'><asp:Label/>
```

**Update:**

Since you are using Entity Framework, you can't use Split function directly. You need to bring the results in memory. One way is to create a custom class and fill it like this:-

```
public class Students
{
   public int Stud_Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName{ get; set; }
   public int Cls_Id{ get; set; }
   public string Room{ get; set; }
   public string Notification{ get; set; }
   public string str1{ get; set; }
   public string str2{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, first fill your custom class with query like this:-

```
List<Students> students = (from c in db.Class
                 join s in db.Students on c.Cls_Id equals s.Cls_Id
                 select new Students
                 {
                     Stud_Id = s.Stud_Id,
                     FirstName = s.FirstName,
                     Cls_Id = c.Cls_Id,
                     Room = c.Room,
                     Notification= c.Notification
                 }).ToList();
```

Finally, iterate through the result and fill up the `str1` & `str2` variables like this:-

```
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    string[] Notifications = student.Notification.Split('/');
    student.str1 = Notifications.FirstOrDefault();
    student.str2 = Notifications.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
 }
```

After this, simply bind your labels with parameters `str1` & `str2`.

Comment: But It display error message like this: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @DucThoPham - Ohh you didn't mentioned it is using entity framework. In that case you can create a custom class and fill it up once you receive the data in your query and make sure, to will have to call `.ToList()` to bring up the results in memory.

Comment: Can u help me demo it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Replace()` like below:

```
<%# ((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Notification")).Replace("/NTFF", string.Empty) %>
```

Please check the syntax first. But should work in this case. Let me know if its not working.

Edit:

Code Behind:

```
var result = from c in db.Class
                 join s in db.Students on c.Cls_Id equals s.Cls_Id
                 select new
                 {
                   Id = s.Stud_Id,
                   FirstName = s.FirstName,
                   ClassId = c.Cls_Id,
                   Room = c.Room,
                   FirstNotification = c.Notification.Split('/')[0],
                   SecondNotification = c.Notification.Split('/')[1]
                 };
```

Then on front end use `FirstNotification` and `SecondNotification` properties.
Note: Above code will throw **Index out of bound** exception when there is no '/' character.

Comment: Sorry but I want slpit it into 2 string. How can I get all 2 string

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know that it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this: First create a DTO to store the result entities with all the fields plus one extra field to store the the list of notifications.

```
public class Result
{
    public int Stud_Id { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    public string Notification { get; set; }
    public string[] Notifications { get; set; }
}

List<Result> result = from c in db.Class
    join s in db.Students on c.Cls_Id equals s.Cls_Id
    select new Result
    {
        Stud_Id = s.Stud_Id,
        ...
        ...
        Notification = c.Notification
    }).ToList();

result.ForEach(r =>
    {
        r.Notifications = r.Notification.Split('/');
    });
```

Now you have two strings in Notifications:

```
Notification[0] = "This Room of C Programming Class";
Notification[1] = "NTFF"
```

You can now use whichever you want to bind in the Lable.

Comment: Sorry how can I binding with syntax ?

Comment: Always try to do something by yourself. Check if Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Notifications[0]")%>' could do your task.

Comment: @DucThoPham - Please mark as answer if this solution solved your query, so that others could benefit from it.